# How to deploy a WCF web service in IIS 8.0 using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, iis-8

I've developed a WCF Restful service with C#, .NET Framework 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010.

On Visual Studio 2010, I have did right click on WCF project, and select `Publish...`. On `Publish web` dialog I have selected `File system` as `publish method`.

This WCF service runs perfectly on my IIS 7, running on a Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits.

I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45) to publish it on an IIS8, running on a Windows Server 2012.

But, when I access the url `http://localhost/MyService.svc/users` I get a 404 NOT FOUND error.

This error page show that it is trying to access the physical path `D:\IIS\MyProject\MyService.svc\users` that is not found.

**What do I have to do to enable my WCF Service?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved this problem following this:
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45

And then doing this:
http://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/publishing-a-wcf-service-on-iis8/.

Comment: Excellent, I had the same problem this morning and this post was exactly correct.  Thank you for answering and posting the 2 links above!